# Widget not working after Force quit App

Tags: java, android, widget, android-ondestroy

I have a widget that works well in all cases except when the app is forced quit. When that happens, any touch or button press on the widget is not working. However, when the app is launched again, the widget works again. Even if I kill the app (by swiping it), the widget still works. My systematic control over the widget is through remoteViews. Do I need to something to handle this case? My guess is that it has to do with onDestroy().

Thanks!

Note: it is similar but not a duplicate of [Widget fails to launch properly after app has been force-stopped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718622/widget-fails-to-launch-properly-after-app-has-been-force-stopped)

Comment: When the app has been quit, why would you expect *anything* to work?

Comment: @ScottHunter There is a service in the app. When the app closed, the widget works. When it is forced quit, it doesn't. Other apps such as Weezer when it is forced quit, then pressing on the widget, the app launches again.